# Javascript parseInt error

Tags: javascript

Making a program to display a table of student grades. Teacher inputs grades from a prompt based on the number of assignments( g <= assignments; in the loop). So I'm making it so it averages the the grades together and displays a Letter grade. Right now, I'm getting an error, that "score is not defined". Not sure why. JSFiddle says it's completely valid, and I have no idea what's wrong.

**UPDATE** 
**Thanks guys, var score = 0; fixed it... But my Loop only works once now, even if I specify it to loop 5 times.**

HERE IS MY FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ndSMa/

```
// second table row begin
    var rowtwo = document.createElement("tr");
    var student = document.createElement("td");
    var studentprompt = prompt("What is the student's name?");
    var studenttext = document.createTextNode(studentprompt);
    student.appendChild(studenttext);
    rowtwo.appendChild(student);




    for (var g = 1; g <= assignments; g++) {
        while (!grade) {
            var grade = prompt("Please enter the student score for assignment" + g + ".");
            var gradecolumn = document.createElement("td");
            var gradetext = document.createTextNode(grade);
            gradecolumn.appendChild(gradetext);
            rowtwo.appendChild(gradecolumn);
            if (parseInt(grade, 10)) {
                // accumulate score
                score += parseInt(grade, 10);
                var totalscore = score/assignments;

            }
            // grade is not a number
            else grade = undefined;
        }



        if (score >= 94) {
            var acolumn = document.createElement("td");
            var atext = document.createTextNode("A");
            totalcolumn.appendChild(atext);
            rowtwo.appendChild(acolumn);
        } else if (score >= 90) {
            var aminuscolumn = document.createElement("td");
            var aminustext = document.createTextNode("A-");
            totalcolumn.appendChild(aminustext);
            rowtwo.appendChild(aminuscolumn);
        } else if (score >= 87) {
            var bpluscolumn = document.createElement("td");
            var bplustext = document.createTextNode("B+");
            totalcolumn.appendChild(bplustext);
            rowtwo.appendChild(bpluscolumn);
        } else if (score >= 84) {
            var bcolumn = document.createElement("td");
            var btext = document.createTextNode("B");
            totalcolumn.appendChild(btext);
            rowtwo.appendChild(bcolumn);
        } else if (score >= 80) {
            var bminuscolumn = document.createElement("td");
            var bminustext = document.createTextNode("B-");
            totalcolumn.appendChild(bminustext);
            rowtwo.appendChild(bminuscolumn);
        } else if (score >= 77) {
            var cpluscolumn = document.createElement("td");
            var cplustext = document.createTextNode("C+");
            totalcolumn.appendChild(cplustext);
            rowtwo.appendChild(cpluscolumn);
        } else if (score >= 74) {
            var ccolumn = document.createElement("td");
            var ctext = document.createTextNode("C");
            totalcolumn.appendChild(ctext);
            rowtwo.appendChild(ccolumn);
        } else if (score >= 70) {
            var cminuscolumn = document.createElement("td");
            var cminustext = document.createTextNode("C-");
            totalcolumn.appendChild(cminustext);
            rowtwo.appendChild(cminuscolumn);
        } else if (score >= 67) {
            var dpluscolumn = document.createElement("td");
            var dplustext = document.createTextNode("D+");
            totalcolumn.appendChild(dplustext);
            rowtwo.appendChild(dpluscolumn);
        } else if (score >= 64) {
            var dcolumn = document.createElement("td");
            var dtext = document.createTextNode("D");
            totalcolumn.appendChild(dtext);
            rowtwo.appendChild(dcolumn);
        } else if (score >= 60) {
            var dminuscolumn = document.createElement("td");
            var dminustext = document.createTextNode("D-");
            totalcolumn.appendChild(dminustext);
            rowtwo.appendChild(dminuscolumn);
        } else if (score < 60) {
            var fcolumn = document.createElement("td");
            var ftext = document.createTextNode("F");
            totalcolumn.appendChild(ftext);
            rowtwo.appendChild(fcolumn);
        }
    }

    tableBody.appendChild(rowtwo);
```

Comment: I don't see a variable declaration for `score`. Is that included elsewhere? Have you tried adding a declaration for it if not, a la `var score = 0;` at the top of your sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

parseInt returns "NaN" when it can't read a number. You're testing it for false, which is not correct. Your `if` isn't going to fail through to the `else`. It's going to evaluate "NaN" as true and do something other than what you expect. So you need to be testing for "NaN" not `true/false` in your test.

Also you need to declare score and set it to 0 first.

Answer (score 1):

Try `var score = 0;` as well if its saying its undefined, and you haven't declared it elsewhere (which you haven't in that code).

`score +=` on the first iteration will attempt to concatenate "undefined"+=0 to undefined0

Answer (score 1):

You must to define your variable "score" before using it to accumulate score.

```
var score = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your for loop to work 5 times, the variable assignments needs to be 5. Hava you checked this? You can check it by the code 
    alert(String(assignments));

If assignments is not 5, you have to do something about it, by saying
    var assignments = 5;

Please tell me if this solved your problem.